# How to autoplay new embedded Facebook videos?

Tags: facebook, video

Since april 2015 Facebook allows to embed video.

Now I want to publish some video's on my website but I would like them to autoplay. There are a couple questions about this but they are not relevant.

This is the code they provide:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
                <script>(function(d, s, id) {  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
                <div class="fb-video" data-allowfullscreen="true" width="100%" height="350" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=1580512992190965"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
                </div></div>
```

Comment: Since the documentation of the plugin doesn’t mention any such option, I think you can assume that as of now this is simply not possible.